# CSS drop down menu - overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overlap

I've made a drop-down menu but when I hover over a parent category, the children appear crowded and overlapping. It seems the children 'elements' are not being placed neatly one below the other; rather, they overlap each other.

I've tried fixing it myself and looking at google and here, but I didn't find any solution that solves this issue. I've also read "Inline elements and padding" guide, but it didn't help me. I'm not a programmer, I'm just doing some customizing of a purchased theme (http://meros11.gostorego.com/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Do I need to post all my code, or can you see it yourself using the developer tools? (such as in Chrome)

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good practice to get in the habit of posting your code here.  Sites may change over time and if someone comes back to view this down the road, they may not be able to see the code because it will have changed.

Comment: please post relevant markup and css or use a fiddle.

Comment: Chances are, you have padding on the li or span elements. also, slow down the scroll on your banner lol, cant read the ads ;(

Comment: You need to adjust the `#nav ul li` padding to be something like `8px 0` or something, and adjust the other paddings to compensate for it being overwritten, like `#nav ul li.first`.

Comment: @JohnManly I'm having some trouble posting my HTML code.. not really sure how to put it in..
AT VikingBlooded I'm actually having some trouble with the slider, I'm planning to slow it down eventually (it's actually very slow to start the slideshow because it needs to load all  the images first.. not sure how to deal with that at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this class, which is applying to all of the menu elements:

```
#nav li.parent a span {
    margin-top: -10px;  /* This is what's making them crowded */
}
```

Looking at the style of your nav menu, this style should only apply to the top level `li` elements (Example Category, Family Tree, Marriages), but it is applying to all of your `a` elements.

I would change the name of this `id` to a `class` (remove the "#nav li.parent a span" and replace with ".[your class name here]" then apply that class to the top level `li` elements (Example Category, Family Tree, Marriages).

Change

```
<li class="level0 nav-1 level-top first parent hasProducts">
```

to

```
<li class="level0 nav-1 level-top first parent hasProducts [YOUR CLASS HERE]">
```

Then in your CSS:

change

```
#nav li.parent a span {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

to

```
.[YOUR CLASS HERE]{
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion to remove the margin on #nav li.parent a span worked perfectly. It did, however, ruin some visual aspects of the menu which i'm working of fixing on now. (The code you posted lost me though, I'm not a programmer, I don't want to mess around so much with the HTML/CSS. In fact, I don't know how I would change the HTML of my site :)) Thanks for the help, I spent at least 2 hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: No problem.  I would have been a bit more thorough, but I was hurried for time.  Glad you figured it out. @user3579613